# Specifying Gem version when building Ruby on Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I'm learning Ruby on Rails using [this excellent tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), and I noticed that the author always specifies the Gem version number in the Gemfile (see [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#code%3agemfile_sqlite_version), [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#code%3ademo_gemfile_sqlite_version_redux), and [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#code%3agemfile_annotate)). Is this something I should get in the habit of doing? If so, how do I know what version to specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to **not** specify the gem version, **until** you have found an incompatibility with a specific gem.

Bundler will itself lock a specific versions of the gems. You just need to remember to use `bundle install --deployment` on the production machine(s), and make upgrades only on your development machine (or in another directory).

It will be very important to have a good test coverage of your project. Without tests, you will not know when an upgrade breaks your application. I humbly suggest the following route:

- run `rake test` *(just to be sure that everything works)*
- run `bundle update`
- run `rake test`

If the test passes, commit the change in `Gemfile.lock`. If the test does not pass, and you want to lock a given gem, *then* specify the version in Gemfile.

You may read about [install --deployment](http://gembundler.com/bundle_install.html) and  [deploying](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html) in the bundler documentation.

Answer (score 1):

"Freezing" gems at specific versions is important, and it is obligatory if you are preparing something for production. Gems, libraries and apps evolve with time -- and for evolving, sometime it is required to change the Gem API, and this offen brokes backward compatibility with previous versions.

There are a few old and good articles regarding "freezing" a Rails version (that's how we call "specifying a Gem version" in the old days), such as [DHH's Freeze is cool, so freeze for goodness sake](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/03/31/freeze-is-cool-so-freeze-for-goodness-sake), and [Should I freeze my Rails application?](http://support.tigertech.net/freeze-rails).

In order to know what version to specify, I recommend you specifying the latest version. Just `gem install gemname` and then `gem list gemname` to see what version you just installed.